# Set the current admin as the default author from the list of options

Tags: php, laravel, admin, laravel-blade, blogs

I'm creating a blog for Laravel App where only admins can post new articles/posts to the blog. In the posts I made an option for the admins to choose who's the author of the post however I'm trying the set the default selected author is the current admin when creating a new post while the edit page it retrieves the author from the database and set it as default.

In the controller I called all the admins to list in them in blade

```
/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    $authors    = Admin::all();
    $categories = Category::all();
    $tags       = Tag::all();
    return view('posts.create', compact('categories', 'tags', 'authors'));
}
```

Than in blade I'm setting a condition where it says if the author_id is not set let the current logged-in admin be the default chosen author.

```
                    <select name="author" id="author" data-placeholder="Choose an Author" class="form-select">
                        @foreach($authors as $author)
                            <option value="{{$author->id}}"
                                @if (!isset($post->author_id))
                                {{ auth()->guard('admin')->user()->id ? 'selected' : '' }}
                                @elseif ((isset($post->author_id) && $author->id == $post->author_id))
                                {{ 'selected' }}
                                @endif>{{ $author->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
```

The above code adds selected to all options and calls the last one in the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if `Auth ID` equals to `Select ID`

```
<select name="author" id="author" data-placeholder="Choose an Author" class="form-select">
                        @foreach($authors as $author)
                            <option value="{{$author->id}}"
                                @if (!isset($post->author_id))
                                  @if(auth()->guard('admin')->user()->id=={{$author->id}})
                                  Selected    
                                  @endif
                                @elseif ((isset($post->author_id) && $author->id == $post->author_id))
                                {{ 'selected' }}
                                @endif>{{ $author->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
```

OR You can do something like this

```
<select name="author" id="author" data-placeholder="Choose an Author" class="form-select">
                        @foreach($authors as $author)
                            <option value="{{$author->id}}"
                                @if (!isset($post->author_id))
                                {{ auth()->guard('admin')->user()->id == {{$author->id}} ? 'selected' : '' }}
                                @elseif ((isset($post->author_id) && $author->id == $post->author_id))
                                {{ 'selected' }}
                                @endif>{{ $author->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
```